# Stop CardView Animation From Another Class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I set an animation on a MaterialCardView in Overview.java

Overview.java

```
private void animate(MaterialCardView cv) {

        Log.d("VIEW", cv.toString());

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(
                cv, "strokeColor",
                Color.parseColor("#00FFEA00"),
                Color.parseColor("#FFFFEA00")
        );
        animator.setDuration(1000);
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);

        animator.start();
    }
```

It's in a RecyclerView so in its on click handler I call v.clearAnimation()

```
        holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Operation_Info_Tab_Activity.class);
                ArrayList<OperationV2> schedule = (ArrayList<OperationV2>) ot.getSchedule();
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Schedule", schedule);
                intent.putExtra("Number", ot.getNumber());
                intent.putExtra("Notified", ot.getIsNotified());

                Log.d("STOP", v.toString());
                v.clearAnimation();
                
//                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I've tried setAnimation(null) and got a nullPointer (because I didn't use .setAnimation() I think). Really unsure why this is happening.

If anyone has any alternatives to the way I'm animating it that might work I'm all ears. Or if anyone knows how to get an Animation object from an ObjectAnimator so I can try .setAnimation().

Comment: So when someone clicks on a card inside of a recyclerview, you want to stop/clear the animation?

Comment: Yep. Currently when the onClick fires the v.clearAnimation() does nothing

Comment: So I would make your animator object global within `Overview.java`, let's call it `objectAnimator` in this example. Then have an `OverviewOnClickListener` interface that your class `Overview.java` implements. The implementation will just call `objectAnimator.cancel()` function to cancel animation. Then in your holder, invoke the callback.

Comment: alright seems a bit hacky but I'll give it a shot! thanks

Comment: @xr100chris oh I forgot to mention in the text - the two code snippets are from different classes. The second is in `RecyclerViewAdapter.java`. I'm not sure if the interface method is still viable in this scenario

Comment: Yeah I figured. `holder.cardview.setOnClickListener` gave it away. lol

It's really not hacky. The only way to make it not appear so is if you use `DataBinding`, then you could define the onClick via xml. I guess you could also use `LiveData` objects, but you would still need to invoke the callback the way I described before. In your adapter constructor, just take `OverviewOnClickListener` as a parameter. Then `OverviewOnClickListener.foo()`

Comment: This worked! But seems I'll need a list of object animators, one for each card in the recycler view. If two animations go off the onclick doesn't stop the right animation. but thanks!